# delete Multiple columns by VBA

Tags: vba

i Have 700 columns in a sheet. I want to delete  more than 650 out of them. If I use range as `A:W` and more then I get `400 Error`.

Is there  any limit to no.  of column deletion in VBA.

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through them from rightmost column and delete them one by one.

```
Sub test()
Dim c As Long, r As Long
    Worksheets(1).Activate
    'populate 700 columns
    For c = 1 To 700
        Cells(1, c).Value = "col " & c
        For r = 2 To 10
            Cells(r, c).Value = "hej " & c & "/" & r
        Next
    Next
    'remove e.g. even columns
    For c = 700 To 1 Step -2
        Columns(c).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This method uses `Select` and `Activate` which is bad practice

Comment: Why is it bad practice @Tim-Stack?

Comment: It is asking for errors, which will pop up very soon. Read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: If you would allow I could add a version of your code converted not to use `Select` and `Activate` to your answer